# Finding a chain map.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

Let $C_2 = \langle T| T^2 = 1 \rangle$ be the group of order 2. Let $R = \mathbb Z$ or $R = \mathbb F_2.$ Let $\mathcal{W}$ be the $C_2$-equivariant cellular chains of $S^{\infty}$ with two cells, $e_n$ and $Te_n,$ of each dimension $n \geq 0,$ and boundary $d(e_{2k + 1}) = (1 - T)e_{2k}$ and $d(e_{2k}) = (1 + T)_{e_{2k} - 1}.$ This gives the resolution $$0 \leftarrow \mathcal{W}_0 \leftarrow \mathcal{W}_1 \leftarrow \dots $$ with each $\mathcal W_n = \langle e_n \rangle \cong R[C_2]$ and homology

$$
H_i(\mathcal W)=
\begin{cases}
R, &  i = 0\\
0, & i > 0
\end{cases}
$$

The tensor product $\mathcal{W} \otimes \mathcal{W}$ is the chain complex with $\bigoplus_{i + j = n}\mathcal{W}_i \otimes \mathcal{W}_j$ in degree $n$ and differential $d(x \otimes y) = dx \otimes y + (-1)^{|x|} x \otimes dy.$ Let $C_2$ act diagonally on $\mathcal{W} \otimes \mathcal{W}: T(x \otimes y) = (Tx) \otimes (Ty).$

$(1)$ With $R = \mathbb F_2,$ find a $C_2$-equivariant chain map $\Delta: \mathcal{W} \to \mathcal{W} \otimes \mathcal{W}$ with $\Delta (e_0) = e_0 \otimes e_0.$

$(2)$ Do the same with $R = \mathbb Z.$

**My thoughts and questions:**

0- why $(1-T)e_0 = e_0 \otimes e_0 - Te_0 \otimes Te_0$? can someone show me the details of the calculation please?

a- Equivariant in this context means $\mathcal{W}$ and $\mathcal{W} \otimes \mathcal{W}$ are $R[C_2]$-modules, and $\Delta$ should be an $R[C_2]$-module homomorphism. The idea of the exercise is to show that $\tau \Delta \neq \Delta$

b- I got a hint to work $e_1$ and $e_2$ first but I do not know the details of doing this. I am guessing I should use the given two maps $d(e_{2k + 1}) = (1 - T)e_{2k}$ and $d(e_{2k}) = (1 + T)_{e_{2k} - 1}$ but still how?

c- I also got the following diagram (maybe it contain mistakes):

> [image]

d- I also, do not know how to use the given differential in my solution to $1$ and $2.$ maybe this is required for solving the following question (which is also given as #3):

With $R = \mathbb F_2 or \mathbb Z,$ find a chain homotopy $\Delta_1: \mathcal{W}_n \to (\mathcal{W} \otimes \mathcal{W})_{n + 1}$ between $\Delta$ and $\tau \Delta.$ That is $d \Delta_1 + \Delta_1 d = \Delta - \tau \Delta.$ Here, $\tau(x \otimes y) = (-1)^{|x||y|} y \otimes x.$

Could someone show me the details of the solution of $(1)$ & $(2),$ please? How can I find the $4 \times 8$ matrix over $\mathbb Z$ for $e_1$? How can I find the $8 \times 12$ matrix for $e_2,$ can someone give me more details please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exercise is essentially asking for a chain-level approximation to the diagonal map $S^\infty \to S^\infty \times S^\infty$.  There is probably a geometric way to write down a Alexander-Whitney map, but let's use your hint and attack the problem algebraically by hand at least for the first few generators.

We are given that $\Delta(e_0) = e_0 \otimes e_0$.  By equivariance, we have $\Delta(Te_0) = Te_0 \otimes Te_0$, so we know what the map $\Delta$ does on the $0$th level.  In fact, $\Delta(Te_k) = T \Delta(e_k)$, so it is enough to define $\Delta$ on $e_k$ for each $k$ and then $\Delta$ will automatically be $C_2$-equivariant.

The next question to ask is what is $\Delta(e_1)$?  The only condition we have is that $\Delta$ is a chain map.  This means that whatever $\Delta(e_1)$ is, it has to satisfy $d \Delta(e_1) = \Delta(d e_1)$.  We can compute the right hand side:
$$\begin{align*}
d \Delta(e_1) &= \Delta(d e_1) \\
&= \Delta(e_0 - Te_0) \\
&= \Delta(e_0) - \Delta(Te_0) \\
&= e_0 \otimes e_0 - Te_0 \otimes Te_0.
\end{align*}$$
So we need to find something whose differential is $e_0 \otimes e_0 - Te_0 \otimes Te_0$.

Let's compute a few differentials: let's try $e_0 \otimes e_1$ first:
$$d(e_0 \otimes e_1) = e_0 \otimes (e_0 - Te_0) = e_0 \otimes e_0 - e_0 \otimes Te_0.$$

Ok, this gives us the $e_0 \otimes e_0$ term in $d\Delta(e_1)$, but we still need $-Te_0 \otimes Te_0$ and a way to cancel out $-e_0 \otimes Te_0$.  But note that $$e_0 \otimes Te_0 - Te_0 \otimes -Te_0 = (e_0 - Te_0) \otimes Te_0 = de_1 \otimes Te_0 = d(e_1 \otimes Te_0).$$ Therefore, we have $$d(e_0 \otimes e_1 + e_1 \otimes Te_0) = e_0 \otimes e_0 - Te_0 \otimes Te_0.$$ So let's set $\Delta(e_1) = e_0 \otimes e_1 + e_1 \otimes Te_0$.

We can play the same game for $\Delta(e_2)$, using our new definition of $\Delta(e_1)$ (and thus $\Delta(Te_1)$).  We have
$$\begin{align*}
d \Delta(e_2) &= \Delta(de_2) \\
&= \Delta(e_1 + Te_1) \\
&= \Delta(e_1) + \Delta(Te_1) \\
&= (e_0 \otimes e_1 + e_1 \otimes Te_0) + (Te_0 \otimes Te_1 + Te_1 \otimes e_0)
\end{align*}$$

Let's compute more differentials; let's try $e_0 \otimes e_2$:
$$d(e_0 \otimes e_2) = e_0 \otimes(e_1 + Te_1) = e_0 \otimes e_1 + e_0 \otimes Te_1.$$

The $e_0 \otimes e_1$ is what we want, but again we have a junk term $e_0 \otimes Te_1$.  We see that we want the $e_1 \otimes Te_0 + Te_0 \otimes Te_1$ terms eventually, so why not kill two birds with one stone and use $$d(e_1 \otimes Te_1) = (e_0 - Te_0) \otimes Te_1 - e_1 \otimes (Te_0 - e_0) = e_0 \otimes Te_1 - Te_0 \otimes Te_1 - e_1 \otimes Te_0 + e_1 \otimes e_0.$$ This leaves us with $e_1 \otimes e_0 + Te_1 \otimes e_0$, which we recognize as $d(e_2 \otimes e_0)$.  So putting this altogether, we have $$d(e_0 \otimes e_2 - e_1 \otimes Te_1 + e_2 \otimes e_0) = e_0 \otimes e_1 + e_1 \otimes Te_0 + Te_1 \otimes e_0 + Te_0 \otimes Te_1 = d(\Delta(e_2)).$$ So we can set $\Delta(e_2) = e_0 \otimes e_2 - e_1 \otimes Te_1 + e_2 \otimes e_0$.

We have not shown that these are the only choices for $\Delta(e_1)$ and $\Delta(e_2)$, and you might be worried that we'll run into an obstruction if this is not the right choice as we continue to lift this map up the chain complex; however, there is a result in homological algebra about lifting maps from free resolutions to acyclic ones that guarantees that this procedure will succeed.

You should try to continue and compute $\Delta(e_3)$, $\Delta(e_4)$, $\ldots$ until you spot a pattern.

In this case, one possible diagonal approximation is given by $$\Delta(e_k) = \sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{i(k-i)} e_i \otimes T^i e_{k-i}.$$  It's tedious, but I leave it to you to actually check this it is a chain map.  You can ignore the signs if you work mod $2$.

---

Editing to answer questions in comments.

1. We can compute $\tau \Delta$ directly, using the formula for $\Delta$ in my answer: $$\tau \Delta (e_k) = \sum_{i=0}^k T^i e_{k-i} \otimes e_i,$$ and simply observe that $\tau \Delta \neq \Delta$.
2. Equivariance means $T \circ \Delta = \Delta \circ T$, where $T$ acts as indicated on $\mathcal{W}$, and diagonally on $\mathcal{W} \otimes \mathcal{W}$.
3. Normally, one uses the method of acyclic models to create these higher diagonal approximations, which is slick but does not give explicit formulae. Alternatively, using a similar method as above, you can deduce $\Delta_1(e_0) = 0$, $\Delta_1(e_1) = e_1 \otimes e_1$, $\ldots$.  I think that in general, $$\Delta_1(e_k) = (-1)^{k+1} \sum_{\substack{0 \leq i < j \leq k \\ j - i \text{ odd}}} e_{k-j+i+1} \otimes T^i e_{j-i}$$ but I don't have very high confidence about the signs (which depend in part on how you define a chain homotopy), so you should double check.  You could probably extract the right signs from Steenrod's [original paper](https://doi.org/10.2307/1969172) "Products of Cocycles and Extensions of Mappings".  Another place to look is this [more recent paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s40062-021-00287-3) by Blumfiel, Medina-Mardones, and Morgan (see Theorem 3.2), but they seem to work mod $2$ only.

Comment: I think also the deep goal of the exercise was to show that $\tau \Delta \neq \Delta$ .... were you able to show this in your solution? if so in which part?

Comment: what is your definition for equivariance?

Comment: And how can we find the required chain homotopy in #3?

Comment: I am confused about the formula you used for computing $d(e_0 \otimes e_1)$ was it that $d = d \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes d$ or $d(x \otimes y) = dx \otimes y + (-1)^{|x|} x \otimes dy$? also, when should we use the first formula?

Comment: Use the version with the sign; you need a sign somewhere otherwise you don't get a valid differential on the tensor product of two chain complexes.

Comment: So you are saying in case of $\mathbb F_2$ the formulas will be the same but with positive signs instead of negative ones.

Comment: did the author ever mentioned how $T$ acts on $\mathcal{W}$?

Comment: Can you please show the details of your calculation for $d(e_0 \otimes e_1)$? when I used the given signed formula it does not give me the same as yours ...... I am also using that $de_0 = e_0.$

Comment: Also, I wanted to thank you for the edit, it is extremely useful!

Comment: What rule tells you that $de_1 \otimes Te_0 = d(e_1 \otimes Te_0)$?

Comment: (1) $T$ sends $e_k$ to $Te_k$ and $Te_k$ to $T^2 e_k = e_k$.  (2) $de_0 = 0$ since there is nothing in chain level "$-1$".  (3) $d(e_1 \otimes Te_0) = de_1 \otimes Te_0 - e_1 \otimes d(Te_0)$, but $d(Te_0) = 0$ since again there is nothing in chain level "$-1$".